# MVVM -- Button Click Command(Could not be found)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, command

I'm very new to the MVVM structure in WPF. I'm trying to write a button-click command in my ViewModel using "Example 1" in [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/274982/Commands-in-MVVM#example1) and for some reason I am having problems with `Command`. I'm getting `The type or namespace name 'Command' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` compiler error. Do I need to include a new namespace, or do I need to include another function in my viewModel?

Comment: As you can see in the tutorial, the `Command` object is a custom type. You need to add the namespace to your viewmodel.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you just typed in the sample, you are missing the definition for `Command`, which is included in their `Apex` project, `Apex.MVVM` namespace. It implements the `ICommand` interface.

Options:

- Download the full source
- Download the Apex binaries and add a reference
- Skip ahead and do [How Does it Work - The Command Class](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/274982/Commands-in-MVVM#hdiw1), which shows the code for `Command`

Comment: So basically I should be able to add that Command class to my project then?

Comment: Yes, if you skip ahead to that section, it looks like it defines what you need. Some kind of preface *should* have warned you about this, but it might have been written assuming you have downloaded the full project or the compiled binaries.

Comment: Understood. I can probably edit it for my specific situation then.